# Create Workflow with Automator.app to reduce file size with Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: acrobat, automator

I have many pdfs that i need to downsize and wanted to create an Application with Automator.app on Mac OS to reduce the file size of a file with Adobe Acrobat Pro, by just dropping the files onto the created application. To a certain point it works fine, however there is a problem with recognising a menu button on the window \"Arrange documents\".

The base of the code was created with the recorder function.

Following code for "Run Apple Script" on an already open file in Adobe

```
on run {input, parameters}

-- Click the “File” menu.
"click menu bar item \"File\" of menu bar 1 of application process \"Acrobat\""

-- Reduced Size PDF...
"click menu item \"Save As Other...\" of menu 1 of menu bar item \"File\" of menu bar 1 of application process \"Acrobat\""

-- Reduced Size PDF...
"click menu item \"Reduced Size PDF...\" of menu 1 of menu item \"Save As Other...\" of menu 1 of menu bar item \"File\" of menu bar 1 of application process \"Acrobat\""

-- Click the “Apply to Multiple” button.
"click UI Element \"Apply to Multiple\" of window \"Reduce File Size\" of application process \"Acrobat\""
```

this part work. The following is the problem where i get stuck.

```
-- 
"click group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of window \"Arrange documents\" of application process \"Acrobat\""
```

I thought about calling it an UI Element or something else but it did not do the trick.
such as

```
-- 
"click UI Element \"Add Files...\" of window \"Arrange documents\" of application process \"Acrobat\""
```

but it does not seem to work.

I'm not sure on how to resolve that issue. I do know the next step would need to be edited as well (of menu 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1).

The next steps from the recording would be:

```
-- Add Open Files...
"click menu item \"Add Open Files...\"of menu 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of window \"Arrange documents\" of application process \"Acrobat\""

-- Click the “Add Files” button.
"click UI Element \"Add Files\" of window \"Open PDF Files\" of application process \"Acrobat\""

-- Click the “OK” button.
"click menu item 1 of group 1 of group 5 of group 1 of window \"Arrange documents\" of application process \"Acrobat\""

-- Click the “Add to original file names:” radio button.
"click radio button \"Add to original file names:\" of group 2 of window \"Output Options\" of application process \"Acrobat\""

-- Click the text field.
"click text field 2 of group 2 of window \"Output Options\" of application process \"Acrobat\""

-- Type '_red'
"keystroke \"_red\""

-- Click the “OK” button.
"click UI Element \"OK\" of window \"Output Options\" of application process \"Acrobat\""

return input

end run
```

Answer (score 1):

They say that Acrobat is not very easy to automatize; it is possible, but there are roadblocks all over the place.

You might onsider to create an Action in Acrobat, and if you want to use a droplet, try automatizing running that Action. This would relieve you to some extent from the dialog issues.

Another possibility would be to see if you could do your optimizing with Acrobat JavaScript (maybe with the necessity to have high privilege scripts, requiring the use of Application-level JavaScripts). If this is possible, you won't have to fiddle around with menus at all, because you can simply use the the do script Applescript command.

In my work with automatizing Acrobat, I did find the UIInspector utility (if I remember correctly, it comes as part of XCode, but should be downloadable individually from the Apple Developer site. This utility gives you the full information about any element of the User Interface, in particular, whether you can access an item or a group by name, or if you have to do so by number.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I guess i give up on that then since i am a beginner in that and i do not seem to find the action in acrobat also the "Accessibility Inspector" said that group 1 of group... is how to address it. Well back to manually. Thanks!